# Query optimization.: Insert few raws from a table into same table after modifiying one or few column:

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Well, I need to insert some rows into a table (DBO.ORDERDATA) with some mathematical modification(here multiplication with -1) to a column(Unit Price) keeping other columns value as it is.

Here is the code: Considering the Northwind DB:

```
CREATE TABLE DBO.ORDERDATA
(
    OrderID INT NOT NULL,
    ProductID INT NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice MONEY NOT NULL,
    Quantity SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    Discount REAL NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO DBO.ORDERDATA
SELECT * FROM DBO.[Order Details]
```

And the insert code follows :

```
INSERT INTO DBO.ORDERDATA (OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice, Quantity, Discount)
    SELECT 
        OrderID, ProductID, UnitPrice * -1, Quantity, Discount 
    FROM 
        DBO.ORDERDATA
    WHERE 
        OrderID = 10530
```

I escaped the inbuilt DBO.[Order Details] table due to many key-constraint, I'm a bit lazy ;)

Finally Any alternatives to above insertion script where I need not to specify all columns name .Please note that in some scenario one column may be Identity column.

All answers and comments will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If OrderID, or a combination of OrderID and ProductID, is the PK, then an insert that duplicates the PK will fail with a PK constraint violation.  You're trying to insert 10530, which is already there.

If OrderID is an IDENTITY autoincrement field, the following should work, and a new OrderID value will be created:

```
INSERT INTO DBO.ORDERDATA(ProductID,UnitPrice,Quantity,Discount)
SELECT ProductID,UnitPrice*-1,Quantity,Discount FROM DBO.ORDERDATA
WHERE OrderID=10530
```

You may wish to avoid dealing with the key constraints, but they are in fact telling you something important about this data.  If, for example, the combination of OrderID and ProductID is the PK, that means the table should have only one record with that combination of key values.  You should not want to insert a duplicate in this manner.

What is the reason are you trying to insert a duplicate?  If you are trying to implement a "credit" on this order, then you might want to think of some way to implement this that doesn't break the data integrity.  The keys are there for a good reason.  You could, for example, add a "transactiontype" field to the composite key, if that is the best description of what this data means.

The same thing is true for trying to insert a record without naming all of the fields.  You can avoid doing so [in the following cases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx), but why do you want to?  The fieldnames are important to the integrity of the insert.

> If a column is not in column_list, the Database Engine must be able to
>   provide a value based on the definition of the column; otherwise, the
>   row cannot be loaded. The Database Engine automatically provides a
>   value for the column if the column:
>
> 1. Has an IDENTITY property. The next incremental identity value is used.
> 2. Has a default. The default value for the column is used.
> 3. Has a timestamp data type. The current timestamp value is used.
> 4. Is nullable. A null value is used.
> 5. Is a computed column. The calculated value is used.